# htaccess: Rewrite URL issue for query string in parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I having issue for re-writing url from

```
http://localhost/cs/compare?slug=wash-safe-industries.html
```

to

```
http://localhost/cs/compare/wash-safe-industries.html
```

I have tried following code in .htaccess but does not work for me, I have also searched various sites but still facing issues

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/?compare/(.*?)/?$ /compare.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Also tried following line of code

```
RewriteRule ^cs/(.*)$ cs/compare.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please help me out thanks

Comment: @anubhava yes it is throwing 404 error

Comment: @anubhava in the cs folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .htaccess in `/cs/` sub-directory:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cs/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^compare/(.+?)/?$ compare.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using following line of code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^compare/(.+?)/?$ compare.php?slug=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write as follows, try this one.

> RewriteRule ^compare/wash-safe-industries.html compare?slug=wash-safe-industries.html